# Android: Contributor for Distributing app on android market?

Tags: android, distribution, google-play

as  we all see Google was increased his country list on android market on ( 30 countries for selling)  and  I  saw some talks here about this theme ,  but  I  did not find quality answer ..

My question is  there  any company or person etc. who make some service  for publishing android app on android market from developers from countries who are not on Google list ???

Is there any company  and if  yes Is there any experience in dealing with ??

(I know  for a alternative market like andappstore,slideme this  are fine but not even close Google market)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some sites, which claim to provide such service, e.g.:

- http://www.androidaz.com/
- http://www.digi-go.com/android/index.html
- http://www.androidpublisher.com/
- http://www.androidconnector.com/index.html

Still, I haven't used them myself so I can't comment on their reliability.

Comment: None of these are working :(  
Did Google force them out of business?  
The only sites I have found are:  
* http://blog.saleandroidapps.com/  
* http://unbouncepages.com/android-developer-in-unsupported-country/